# Can't use trial purchase id `android.test.purchased`

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I prefer to use `android.test.purchased` for in-app purchase flow testing. but recently got an error and can't use it, i can't click buy in test box.
This is my code

```
ProductDetails productDetails = skuDetailsINAPMap.get(productId);


if (productDetails == null) {
    return "Product ID invalid";
}
ImmutableList<BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams> productDetailsParamsList =
        ImmutableList.of(
                BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                        .build()
        );

BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
        .build();

BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingFlowParams);
```

Any suggestion or tips would be appreciated.Thanks

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYjaV.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the code of your test & the exact error

Comment: @PradeepKumar I have updated the error picture when I bought it

Comment: Kindly give some clarity on the error that you are facing, to investigate further.

Comment: @PradeepKumar i can't click buy when test box showing. please see attached picture